# IntegrityError at /accounts/regist_save/ happens

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

IntegrityError at /accounts/regist_save/ 
NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_newuser.user_id
error happens .I wrote in

**views.py**

```
def regist(request):
    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'regist_form': regist_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form, 
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/regist.html', context)

@require_POST
def regist_save(request):

    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST" and regist_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                regist = regist_form.save(commit=False)
                regist.is_staff = True
                regist.save()

                profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
                sex = request.POST.get("sex", "")
                print(1111)
                print(sex)
                profile.save()
    else:
        print(regist_form.errors)
        print(profile_form.errors)
    return redirect('detail')
```

**regist.html**

```
 <div class="form-group-lg">

    <label for="id_username">Username</label>

    {{ regist_form.username }}

  </div>

  <div class="form-group-lg">

    <label for="id_email">Email</label>

    {{ regist_form.email }}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group-lg">

    <label for="id_password">Password</label>

    {{ regist_form.password1 }}

  </div>



  <div class="form-group-lg">
    <label for="id_password">Password2</label>

    {{ regist_form.password2 }}
    <p class="help-block">{{ regist_form.password2.help_text }}</p>

  </div>



  {% load static %}
  <div class="form-group-lg">
    <label for="birthday">Date</label>

    <select id="year" class="form-control year" name="year">
      <option value="">--</option>
    </select>
    Year
    <select id="month" class="form-control month" name="month">
      <option value="">--</option>
    </select>
    Month
    <select id="day" class="form-control day" name="day">
      <option value="">--</option>
    </select>
    Day
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group-lg">
    <label for="sex">SEX</label>
    <select id="sex" class="form-control sex" name="sex">
      <option value="">--</option>
      <option value="male">male</option>
      <option value="female">female</option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <script src="{% static 'accounts/register.js' %}"></script>


      <button type="submit" class="btn-lg regist">REGIST</button>

      <input name="next" type="hidden" />

  {% csrf_token %}

</form>
```

**regist.js**

```
$(() => {
    for (let i = 1900; i < 2020; i++) {
        $("#year").append(`<option value="${i}">${i}</option>`);
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
        $("#month").append(`<option value="${i}">${i}</option>`);
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
        $("#day").append(`<option value="${i}">${i}</option>`);
    }
})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class NewUser(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        birthday = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, default=None)
        sex = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

in forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from .models import User
from .models import NewUser

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email','password1','password1',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = (
            "birthday", "sex"
        )
```

I really cannot understand why this error happens because I did not write user_id  in NewUser models.I think Integrity Error means columns cannot be found in `Model.OneToOneField` can be connected withUser and NewUser's model .I think this error means I should prepare user_id in New User model but if my thinking is right, I cannot understand why.How should I fix this?What should I write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because in the NewUser model, the **user** field is a required field. In the ProfileForm the user field is not included. So when the ProfileForm tries to save the NewUser without user attached to it, it results in the above mentioned error.

What we have to do is to attach the user to the instance before actual save happens:

```
profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
profile.user = registered_user # you can get the user from the registerform above
profile.save()
```